# Autodependencies for make generate the .d files but are not reading them

Tags: c++, makefile

I am trying to write a makefile for my C++ program that will generate autodependencies.  I reviewed [this tutorial](http://scottmcpeak.com/autodepend/autodepend.html) and have also been reviewing the GNU make manual.  It seems like make is generating my .d files but not reading them, or that it reads them but won't use them for some reason.

My project is laid out with these directories:

- src for .cpp files
- include for .hpp files
- makedeps for .d files
- objects for .o files
- bin for the final executable

Here is my makefile:

```
BIN=bin
SRC=src
INC=include
DEP=makedeps
OBJ=objects
# sources are like 'src/main.cpp'
sources=$(wildcard $(SRC)/*.cpp)
# objects are like 'objects/main.o'
objects=$(subst $(SRC),$(OBJ),$(sources:.cpp=.o))
# dependencies are like 'makedeps/main.d'
deps=$(subst $(SRC),$(DEP),$(sources:.cpp=.d))
GPP=g++
CPPFLAGS=-std=c++11
LINKARGS=-L/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu

# used by the implicit rules that the dependency files use:
CXX=$(GPP)

$(BIN)/app.exe : $(objects)
    $(GPP) $(CPPFLAGS) $(LINKARGS) $(objects) -lcurl -o $(BIN)/app.exe

# on the first pass this should fail, but it should discover how 
# to build these dependencies and then build them and load them in.
# once they are loaded in, it should know how to build the object files.
-include $(deps)

# this produces the dependency files, the sed command puts directory prefixes
# before the files
$(DEP)/%.d : $(SRC)/%.cpp
    @set -e; rm -f $@; \
    $(GPP) -I$(INC) -MM $(CPPFLAGS) $< > $@.$$$$; \
    sed 's,\($*\)\.o[ :]*,$(OBJ)/\1.o : ,g' < $@.$$$$ > $@; \
    rm -f $@.$$$$

.PHONY:clean
clean:
    rm -f $(OBJ)/*.o
    rm -f $(DEP)/*.d
    rm -f $(BIN)/*
```

When I run make, it generates all the dependency files under the 'makedeps' directory, here is their concatenated output:

```
objects/DownloadBuffer.o : src/DownloadBuffer.cpp include/DownloadBuffer.hpp
objects/Downloader.o : src/Downloader.cpp include/Downloader.hpp \
 include/DownloadBuffer.hpp
objects/main.o : src/main.cpp include/Downloader.hpp
```

I found this in the GNU make manual documentation on implicit rules:

> Compiling C++ programs: `n.o` is made automatically from `n.cc`, `n.cpp`, or `n.C` with a recipe of the form ‘`$(CXX) $(CPPFLAGS) $(CXXFLAGS) -c`’

which is why I set CXX=$(GPP) above.

However, the object files were not produced.  Here is the make output:

```
mike@ubuntu:~/NetBeansProjects/CppApplication_1$ make -f mk.mk clean
rm -f objects/*.o
rm -f makedeps/*.d
rm -f bin/*
mike@ubuntu:~/NetBeansProjects/CppApplication_1$ make -f mk.mk 
g++ -std=c++11 -L/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu objects/DownloadBuffer.o objects/Downloader.o objects/main.o -lcurl -o bin/app.exe
g++: error: objects/DownloadBuffer.o: No such file or directory
g++: error: objects/Downloader.o: No such file or directory
g++: error: objects/main.o: No such file or directory
make: *** [bin/app.exe] Error 1
```

please note that the .d files were removed first, and that I confirmed they were created when make ran.  After carefully reading [this section on include directives](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Include), I have the impression that make should try (again) to include these .d files after they have been created.

Would somebody please explain why the object files were not generated?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot rely on implicit rules if your targets have a path separator due to the way implicit rule lookup works, the most immediate way to fix your issue is to provide an explicit recipe after `$(BIN)/app.exe`

```
$(objects):
    $(GPP) $(CPPFLAGS) $(CXXFLAGS) -c $^ -o $@
```

That said, GCC has had better dependency generation for some time now but it looks like the documentation hasn't caught up yet. You can generate dependencies as a side-effect of compilation using `-MMD` which means you can get rid of all the `sed` crud (`-MP` adds dummy targets for headers to avoid problems if you delete them).

Your Makefile would look something like this

```
BIN := bin
SRC := src
INC := include
OBJ := objects

app     := $(BIN)/app.exe
sources := $(wildcard $(SRC)/*.cpp)
objects := $(subst $(SRC),$(OBJ),$(sources:.cpp=.o))
deps    := $(objects:.o=.d)

CXX      := g++
CPPFLAGS := -I $(INC) -MMD -MP
CXXFLAGS := -std=c++11
LDFLAGS  := -L /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu
LDLIBS   := -lcurl

$(app) : $(objects)
    $(CXX) $(LDFLAGS) $^ $(LDLIBS) -o $@

$(OBJ)/%.o: $(SRC)/%.cpp
    $(CXX) $(CPPFLAGS) $(CXXFLAGS) -c $^ -o $@

.PHONY: clean
clean: ; $(RM) $(objects) $(deps) $(app)

-include $(deps)
```

A few other notes you can see from the file

- Use `:=` instead of `=` unless you have a need for the latter
- If your headers are in a separate folder you'll need to add the path
- Outputting dependencies in the same directory as your objects is simpler when using GCC's auto dependency generator. You can change the output file with `-MF` if necessary.
- You don't need to provide `CPPFLAGS` when linking, it isn't performing any preprocessing.
- You should probably stick to the default linker recipe & variables (and `CXX` for that matter).
- Use automatic variables (`$@` etc) where possible in recipes.

If you really want to use the implicit rules you would need to do something like strip the paths from your object files and change to the object dir beforehand.

Comment: I'm confused, you said I should have an explicit recipe for creating my object files, but the .d files are supposed to create that recipe, won't the redundant rules conflict with one another?  I also never knew that CPPFLAGS was only meant to be used with pre-processing (and I think you meant compilation too right?).  I was using it to hold -std=c++11, judging from your solution I guess the linker doesn't need to know the standard.

Comment: So I take it that make will merge separate rules for the same target, am I interpreting that right?

Comment: OMG it worked! and I didn't have to change a thing!  I think that's the most beautiful make file I have ever seen, thanks a million.

Comment: You can have multiple rules for a target as long as only one of them has recipes, make will merge all of the prerequisites. `CPPFLAGS` is for the **C** **p** re **p** rocessor. When making your own recipes it's good practice to keep them similar to the implicit rules. As for which flags are used where you can check GCC's [options documentation](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Option-Summary.html). As you can see `-std` controls the source dialect, by the time the linker is called you have binary objects and it doesn't care what language they were originally.

Comment: @msknapp come to think of it `-std` should be in `CXXFLAGS`.